# How to write an xml annotation in Java for a self-contained tag with attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-binding

I'm using the annotations from the package `javax.xml.bind.annotation` to construct SKOS XML files. I have some trouble about the best way to realize lines like the following (please, observe that the `rdf` prefix has been set in the `package-info.java` file):

```
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme" />
```

Currently, I do it by defining a class and by adding a property to the class, e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "type")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Type{
  @XmlAttribute(name="rdf:resource")
  protected final String res="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme";              
}
```

and then I create a field in the class that I'm going to serialize, e.g.

```
@XmlElement(name="type")
private Type type = new Type();
```

Is this the only way or I can save time by using a more compact approach?

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you are asking.  Could you provide some additional details?

Comment: First, let me thank you for the interest. Please, ignore everything from "Currently, I do it...". The question is: How can you write through JAXB the entry `<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme" />` in a very compact way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

### Java Model

**Type**

JAXB derives default names from classes and packages, so you only need to specify a name if it difers from the default.  Also you should not include the prefix as part of the name,

```
package forum21674070;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Type {

      @XmlAttribute
      protected final String res="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme";

}
```

**package-info**

The `@XmlSchema` annotation is used to specify the namespace qualification.  The use of `@XmlNs` to specify the prefix is not guaranteed to result in that prefix being used in the marshalled XML, but JAXB impls tend to do this (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html).

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns={
                @XmlNs(prefix="rdf", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme")
        }
)
package forum21674070;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```
package forum21674070;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Type.class);

        Type type = new Type();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(type, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:type xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme" rdf:res="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme"/>
```